# How do you retrieve data from Windows 8 app resources?

Tags: javascript, html, json, windows-8

I need to retrieve data to my **titles from my resourses**.
Here is HTML:

```
<div 
    id="selectCurrencySource" 
    data-win-control="Controls.SelectCurrencySource" 
    data-win-options="{sources: [{title: 'AAA', source: 'AAA'}, {title: 'BBB', source: 'BBB'}, {title: 'CCC', source: 'CCC'}], }"
>
</div>
```

I have resourses string: AAA, BBB, CCC.

But **data-win-options** can't be easily replaced with **data-win-res**.

What's the way to do it?

Thank you.